# Where is start point that custom storage for draw.io

Tags: draw.io

I want to add new storage such as gitlab/gitea/gogs for draw.io,

But it's hard for me to find the start point, just with basic javascript dev experiences.
I know should focus on webapp sources, but no idea about the

Comment: Is this what you are looking for : https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000067790-how-to-create-and-use-custom-libraries-

Comment: @TechFree, No it's about add library, not the storage, such as github, google drive